# How to authenticate WFS requests being made to geoserver through openlayers application?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs, authentication, iis

I posted this question [How to access geoserver web services on a backend server through openlayers web application hosted on another server via IIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/284713/how-to-access-geoserver-web-services-on-a-backend-server-through-openlayers-web) and @IanT helped me to expose our web services running on a backend server so they load when logging into our openlayers web app. When you first load the app, you must supply your domain credentials and then the site and services load. However, there is a tool in the app that makes wfs requests to the geoserver, and these requests are getting blocked and I am getting the 401 unauthorized message in the console.

How can I authenticate these requests being made from the application?

Our web app is running on IIS and the credentials being supplied are windows domain credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to make a modification to the fetch request in the code to include credentials, as shown on this site:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch